# load two cms on one server

Tags: cms, cherrypy

i have been searching on net to know if it's possible (or allowable, as in no conflict ) to use two cms's on one server. Like currycms ( http://currycms.com/ ) and cherrypy ( http://www.cherrypy.org/ ). or ( any two servers. ).

situation is my company web page (made by another company) is running on a server. For new requirements ( pages to be made viewable to few employees where ever they are), i need to access database using python and show results on web page (cherrypy I think will work well for this).

Question is will loading cherrypy create any conflict with other existing cms ( currycms in this case ).

How do i install cherrypy on web server.

Answer (score 1):

> Question is will loading cherrypy create any conflict with other existing cms ( currycms in this case )

No, it shouldn't. And you always can use reverse proxy, for e.g. nginx, behind your cms. All you need is that cherrypy use different port from apache/nginx (whatever you will use for currycms)

Comment: great. can you throw more insight. As in, web server <--> nginx <--> cherrypy <--> python script <--> web page